# if, elif , else syntax in python

Tags: python, if-statement

The program below allows me to use the mouse and keys to create shapes in a small box that is produced. I'm having trouble understanding two statements in the code below.

From the code below, how does python change the size when the + key is pressed in the first if statement(same with the next elif statement for -)? Furthermore, how does the size increase when the + button is pressed more than once in a row. The if statement nested in the statement below, should not allow the size to change due to last_key != "+": being False because after pressing the "+ key once that value would now be stored as last_key. I've looked over this for a while, but cant seem to catch onto the flow.

```
def main():
 size = INITIAL_SIZE         # current diameter of circle or length of square
 set_fill_color(1, 0, 0)     # shapes are initially red
 last_key = ""               # no key pressed yet
 drawing_circle = False      # are we drawing circles?
 drawing_square = False      # are we drawing squares?
 mouse_was_down = False      # was the mouse button most recently down?

while not window_closed():
    if is_key_pressed("+"):     # increase size?
        if last_key != "+":
            size = min(size + SIZE_CHANGE, MAX_SIZE)
        last_key = "+"
    elif is_key_pressed("-"):   # decrease size?
        if last_key != '-':
            size = max(size - SIZE_CHANGE, MIN_SIZE)
        last_key = '-'
    elif is_key_pressed("r"):   # draw in red?
        set_fill_color(1, 0, 0)
        last_key = "r"
    elif is_key_pressed("g"):   # draw in green?
        set_fill_color(0, 1, 0)
        last_key = "g"
    elif is_key_pressed("b"):   # draw in blue?
        set_fill_color(0, 0, 1)
        last_key = "b"
    elif is_key_pressed("c"):   # draw circles?
        drawing_circle = True
        drawing_square = False
        last_key = "c"
    elif is_key_pressed("s"):   # draw squares?
        drawing_circle = False
        drawing_square = True
        last_key = "s"
    else:
        last_key = ""           # no key pressed

    if mouse_down():
        if not mouse_was_down:  # beginning of a mouse click?
            if drawing_circle:
                draw_circle(mouse_x(), mouse_y(), size/2)
            elif drawing_square:
                draw_rectangle(mouse_x() - size/2, mouse_y() - size/2, size, size)
        mouse_was_down = True
    else:
        mouse_was_down = False

    request_redraw()
    sleep(0.05)
```

start_graphics(main)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. As you know, Python indentation is critical. Is the `while` loop meant to be free-standing as shown, or part of `main()`.  What about the `start_graphics(main)` which isn't indented enough?  In general, type the code as you'd like it displayed with no tabs, then copy'n'paste into the edit box, then select it and use the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent it all.

Comment: Also, you set `last_key` to `""`, which is not equal to `"+"`, so it's quite possible that if you press the `+` key, release it, and then press it again, that the size will be incremented twice.

Comment: It looks like the nested `if` is to prevent the size from increasing if the `+` key is pressed and held. I say this because, 0.05 seconds after **any** key press, `last_key` is set to an empty string.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I had no idea SO would auto-indent code in that way. I always just popped it into a word processor and added an indent level to everything.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while not window_closed()` will loop the block until you close the window.

`if is_key_pressed("+")` will trigger into that block when you have the "+" key held down.

`if last_key != "+"` ensures that you don't end up "hitting +" a thousand times because the CPU is faster than your finger.

`size = min(size + SIZE_CHANGE, MAX_SIZE)` changes the size to `size+SIZE_CHANGE`, unless that would be bigger than `MAX_SIZE`, in which case it changes it to `MAX_SIZE` instead.

`last_key = "+"` is just clean up to make sure the `if last_key !=` clauses work in all the other `if/elif` conditionals. The key part is that this happens AFTER the rest of the block works, so if you'd hit anything but "+" last, then pressed "+", it will enter the `is_key_pressed` conditional block, check if `last_key` is "+" (it's not), change the `size`, then set last_key equal to "+". Then, since your computer is fast, it will almost INVARIABLY enter the `is_key_pressed` conditional again (since you've almost certainly not released your finger from the key in the time it takes your computer to do a few cycles), but this time `last_key` will be equal to `"+"`, so it won't execute again.

Comment: very helpful. Will work on cleaning up my code as Johnathan Leffler suggests.